# .Net Core Logging to PostgreSQL with Serilog Not Working

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, .net-core, serilog

I'm using Serilog to log Postgresql database
Here is my Serilog Configuration

1. Here is my appsettings.json -> { Also tried different configurations }

```
"Serilog": {
    "Using": [ "Serilog.Sinks.PostgreSQL.Configuration" ],
    "MinimumLevel": "Debug",
    "Enrich": [ "WithMachineName" ],
    "WriteTo": [
      {
        "Name": "PostgreSQL",
        "Args": {
          "connectionString": "my-connection-string",
          "tableName": "log",
          "needAutoCreateTable": true
        }
      }
    ]
  },

  "Columns": {
    "message": "RenderedMessageColumnWriter",
    "message_template": "MessageTemplateColumnWriter",
    "level": {
      "Name": "LevelColumnWriter",
      "Args": {
        "renderAsText": true,
        "dbType": "Varchar"
      }
    },
    "raise_date": "TimestampColumnWriter",
    "exception": "ExceptionColumnWriter",
    "properties": "LogEventSerializedColumnWriter",
    "props_test": {
      "Name": "PropertiesColumnWriter",
      "Args": { "dbType": "Json" }
    },
    "machine_name": {
      "Name": "SinglePropertyColumnWriter",
      "Args": {
        "propertyName": "MachineName",
        "writeMethod": "Raw"
      }
    }
  },
```

2. Here is Program.cs

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json")
                .Build();

            //Initialize Logger
            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .ReadFrom.Configuration(config)
                .CreateLogger();
            try
            {
                Log.Information("Application Starting.");
                CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Log.Fatal(ex, "The Application failed to start.");
            }
            finally
            {
                Log.CloseAndFlush();
            }
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseSerilog()
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
```

3. Here is Controller

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyApp
{
    [ApiController]
    public class AuthenticationController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IAuthenticationService _authenticationService;
        private readonly ILogger<AuthenticationController> _logger;
        public AuthenticationController(
            IAuthenticationService authenticationService,
            ILogger<AuthenticationController> logger)
        {
            this._authenticationService = authenticationService;
            this._logger = logger;
        }

        [Route("test-log")]
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult LOG()
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Hello World");
            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

After startup the table has been created, but there is no record.
Also tested Serilog logging whether than Microsoft but got same problem.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the Serilog.Sinks.PostgreSQL package hasn't been updated to support Npgsql 5.0. In fact they are still trying target .NET Framework, but Npgsql 5.0 only supports .NET Core.

There is an issue open on Github here: https://github.com/b00ted/serilog-sinks-postgresql/issues/34

By the way, you can debug Serilog problems by adding this to your startup configuration:

```
        SelfLog.Enable(msg =>
        {
            Debug.Print(msg);
            Debugger.Break();
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
   var connectionString = "User ID=postgres;Password=yourPassword;Host=localhost;Port=yourPort;database=dbName;";
   var tableName = "Logs";

   Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
       .MinimumLevel.Information()
       .WriteTo.PostgreSQL(
      connectionString,
      tableName,
      restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information,
      needAutoCreateTable: true,
      respectCase: true)
       .CreateLogger();

   Log.Information("This is an informational message.");
   Log.Warning("This is a warning message.");
   Log.Error("This is an error message.");
   Log.Fatal("This is a fatal message.");

   Console.WriteLine("Logging done. Check your PostgreSQL database.");

   Log.CloseAndFlush();
}
```

This code worked for me. And don't forget to make needAutoCreateTable: true as by default it is false and if you don't have Table present it will add for you.
And I am using the following packages

```
 <PackageReference Include="Serilog" Version="3.0.1" />
 <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.PostgreSQL" Version="2.3.0" />
 <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.PostgreSQL.Configuration" Version="1.0.1" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing a similar situation, although I was configuring it in Program.cs via `.WriteTo.PostgreSQL()` in *Program.cs*.

In my case, the solution was to set to `false` the param **'useCopy'**.

Example:

```
...
.WriteTo.PostgreSQL(
  connectionString: configuration.GetConnectionString("LoggerConnection").ToString(),
  tableName: "yourtable",
  columnOptions: columnWriters,
  restrictedToMinimumLevel: LogEventLevel.Information,
  needAutoCreateTable: true,
  respectCase: true,
  useCopy: false // <-----------------
)
...
```

Maybe you can try doing the same in your appsettings.json configuration.